# If Else statement giving error while installing an application in powershell

Tags: powershell, installation, echo

Creating a script for installation of Software on windows via PowerShell, however stuck on an error, following is the code for it.

```
 $software = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.Name -like "*myapplication*"} 
if ($software.Version -ne "1.0.0")  {msiexec.exe /i 'C:\Program Files\myapplication.msi' /qr} {Write-host "Executing the upgrade"} 
else
{
Write-host "Correct version is installed"
}
```

The logic here is if the desired application version is not equal to v1.0.0 then run the installer or else get a message correct version is installed, i am able to install the application if the desired version condition is not met however if the version is the desired one then it should echo that "Correct version is installed" but no, it gives some error regarding else statement as below,

```
The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:5
+ else <<<< 
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am scratching my head for long time at guessing where i am wrong, also there is no space after else statement, Kindly help!

Comment: You've made it harder to identify the problem because your code formatting is *terrible*. If you're using VS Code or a similar development environment, you can have it automatically format your code so it's more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

Unfortunately this error message isn't very helpful. Most languages would say something like:

> Else without if

The `else` must follow as the very next statement block after the `if`:

```
if ($software.Version -ne "1.0.0")  {
    msiexec.exe /i 'C:\Program Files\myapplication.msi' /qr
} # If block finished, expecting elseif or else
{
    Write-host "Executing the upgrade"
} 
else # Else without if?!
{
    Write-host "Correct version is installed"
}
```

### Resolution

You should resolve the issue by removing the closing and opening curly brackets between `msiexec` and the `Write-Host`, bringing those statements into the `if` block, as they both need to be executed when that condition is true.

If you must keep the `msiexec` and `Write-Host` statements on the same line, then use a semicolon to separate them. e.g.

```
if ($software.Version -ne "1.0.0")  {
    msiexec.exe /i 'C:\Program Files\myapplication.msi' /qr;Write-host "Executing the upgrade"
} 
else
{
    Write-host "Correct version is installed"
}
```

Comment: Wow! @mjsqu , i never tought of this, i have tested it now , it works really fine. Thanks much.